How to export only one animation?
I have a scene with an Unreal rig/mesh and I have imported several animation tracks so that I can apply the same tweak to all of them. But I cannot figure out how to export only one animation to an FBX. I have tried exporting selected only, visible only, etc., but when I export the animated rig, all the animations go into the FBX. When the FBX is imported into Unreal, it imports multiple animations.
How can I export the animations one at a time?
